# php code to display icon on active button

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I am working on cakephp 1.3..

i have button and value displaying inside button coming from database.

I want to show arrow icon on my active button only..

now the active arrow icon is displaying in all button...inside forloop.

plz help me to do this..

below is my code

```
 <?php
     foreach($modes as &$mo)
     { 
       $temp = "Road Vs "; $mo = strtolower($mo);
?>
  <li class="active">
    <input name="data[Customer][mode]" class="railbtn" type="submit" id="mode" value="<?php echo $temp.$mo; ?>">
    <span class="arrow">
       <?php echo $this->Html->image('red_arrow.png', array('alt' => '')); ?>
    </span>
 </li>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: write the condition on li class....!!!
<li class="<?php if(some condition){ echo "active"; } ?>">

Comment: i need to display only this arrow on selected active button <span class="arrow">
       <?php echo $this->Html->image('red_arrow.png', array('alt' => '')); ?>
    </span>...

Comment: but i can not understand how to put this in condition and what condition should apply

Comment: put the same condition before <span></span>

Comment: How you are deciding which button to be set active with icon?

Comment: Here is the example to put arrow button on your submit button    



<li class="active">
<button class="railbtn" type="submit" name="data[Customer][mode]" id="mode" > <?php if(condition is true){ ?><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i><?php } ?><?php echo $temp.$mo; ?></button>
</li>

Answer (score 0):

You should add a condition in your for loop 
Like this

```
<?php
// you need to send button unique name to controller 
foreach($modes as &$mo)
     { 
       $temp = "Road Vs "; $mo = strtolower($mo);  ?>
      <li class="<?php echo ($mo == $selectedUniqueButtonID) ? 'active' : '' ?>">
        <input name="data[Customer][mode]" class="railbtn" type="submit" id="mode" value="<?php echo $temp.$mo; ?>">
        <?php if($mo == $selectedUniqueButtonID){ ?>
            <span class="arrow">
               <?php echo $this->Html->image('red_arrow.png', array('alt' => '')); ?>
            </span> 
        <?php } ?>
     </li>
 <?php 
} ?>
```

Controller  code

```
$selectedUniqueButtonID = $this->data['Customer']['mode'];
$this->set('selectedUniqueButtonID',$selectedUniqueButtonID);
```

Comment: plz let me know on which class basis arrow is displaying

Comment: plz check again i have modified my ans. kind regards

Comment: now when i click on the button road vs air...then icon shows only on that button

Comment: first tell me in case of i=0 my code is working or not? just for dummy

Comment: ok now let me know when we click on 'road vs air' button then is there page reload or just sliding the menu or data receive on ajax basis

Comment: ok then you should pass any unique id or name to your controller so we can identify click button id. now can we identify button id or its unique name on our controller function according to your code ?

Comment: i have modify code plz check. if still have prob then plz let me know

Comment: which output you are not getting?